# Building libmemcached with SASL on Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, debian, sasl, libmemcached

I'm trying to build `libmemcached-1.0.18` on Debian Wheezy with `libsasl2` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so` and `memcached` in `/usr/bin/memcached`. When I run `./configure --with-memcached-sasl --prefix=/opt/libmemcached` I end up with the following configuration:

```
Configuration summary for libmemcached version 1.0.18

* Installation prefix:       /opt/libmemcached
* System type:               unknown-linux-gnu
* Host CPU:                  x86_64
* C Compiler:                cc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
* C Flags:                   -g -O2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-pragmas -Wall -Wextra -Wunsuffixed-float-constants -Wjump-misses-init -Wno-attributes -Waddress -Warray-bounds -Wbad-function-cast -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wfloat-equal -Wformat-security -Wformat=2 -Wformat-y2k -Wlogical-op -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wnormalized=id -Woverride-init -Wpointer-arith -Wpointer-sign -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wswitch-enum -Wtrampolines -Wundef -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -funsafe-loop-optimizations -Wclobbered -Wunused -Wunused-result -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-local-typedefs -Wwrite-strings -fwrapv -pipe -fPIE -pie -Wpacked
* C++ Compiler:              c++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2
* C++ Flags:                 -g -O2 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-pragmas -Wall -Wextra -Wno-attributes -Waddress -Warray-bounds -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Wformat-y2k -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wlogical-op -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wnormalized=id -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wswitch-enum -Wtrampolines -Wundef -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -funsafe-loop-optimizations -Wc++11-compat -Wclobbered -Wunused -Wunused-result -Wunused-variable -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-local-typedefs -Wwrite-strings -Wformat-security -fwrapv -pipe -fPIE -pie -Wpacked
* CPP Flags:                  -fvisibility=hidden
* LIB Flags:                 
* Assertions enabled:        no
* Debug enabled:             no
* Shared:                    yes
* Warnings as failure:       no
* SASL support:              yes
* make -j:                   3
* VCS checkout:              no
```

Yet, when I build with `make && make install` the resulting `libmemcached.so` is missing `sasl_*` symbol definitions. This breaks `pylibmc`. Here's the output from `nm -D /opt/libmemcached/lib/libmemcached.so`:

```
...
U sasl_client_init
U sasl_client_new
U sasl_client_start
U sasl_client_step
U sasl_dispose
U sasl_done
U sasl_errstring
...
```

What options should I use with `./configure` to build `libmemcached` with SASL support?

Answer (score 0):

This i do it with "--enable-sasl" option. That works for me.